# Induction Using AM-GM Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have the following problem that I am stuck on.

> Recall the AM-GM inequality: for set of distinct positive real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$, we have $\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}}$. Suppose $a_{n}=(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+n^{2})^{n}$ and $b_{n}=n^{n}(n!)^{2}$. Show that $a_{n}\geq b_{n}$ for all $n$.

I know that I clearly need to use induction. For the base case, we have $a_{1}=(1^{2})^{1}=1$ and $b_{1}=1^{1}(1!)^{2}=1$ so that $a_{1}\geq b_{1}$. Now I assume that the statement holds for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+k^{2})^{k}\geq k^{k}(k!)^{2}$. We must show that the statement holds for $k+1$. I keep getting stuck on the inductive step (perhaps I am missing something obvious?). Here's what I have so far:

> $\begin{split}
> (1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+(k+1)^{2})^{k+1}&=(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+(k+1)^{2})^{k}(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+(k+1)^{2})\\
> \\
> &\geq (1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+k^{2})^{k}(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots(k+1)^{2})\\
> \\
> &\geq k^{k}(k!)^{2}(1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+(k+1)^{2}) \hspace{0.25cm} (\mathrm{by\:inductive\:hypothesis})\\
> \\
> &=k^{k}(k+1)(k!)^{2}\frac{1^{2}+2^{2}+\cdots+(k+1)^{2}}{k+1}\\
> \\
> &\geq k^{k}(k+1)(k!)^{2}\frac{1+2+\cdots+(k+1)}{k+1}\\
> \\
> &\geq k^{k}(k+1)(k!)^{2}\sqrt[k+1]{1\cdot 2\cdots(k+1)} \hspace{0.25cm} (\mathrm{by\:AM-GM\:inequality})\\
> \\
> &=k^{k}(k+1)(k!)^{2}[(k+1)!]^{1/(k+1)}
> \end{split}$

But from here, I have no idea how to show that this quantity is larger than $(k+1)^{k+1}[(k+1)!]^{2}$. Am I on the right track? Is there something simple that I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: I'd say your inequalities are so strong - for instance in the first inequality you miss $(k+1)^2$, so in this case equality cannot take place.

Comment: I left off $(k+1)^{2}$ so I could use my inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Why would you use induction and not just plug in the numbers directly into the AM-GM inequality you are given?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I thought since this is for all $n$ I had to use induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x_i=i^2$ in the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so stupid for overthinking it!

Answer (score 1):

No induction required here: observe the A.M.-G.M. inequality can be written as
$$\Bigl(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}\Bigr)^{\!n}\ge x_1x_2\dotsm x_n,$$
and the given inequality as
$$\Bigl(\frac{1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2}{n}\Bigr)^{\!n}\ge (1\cdot 2\dotsm n)^2=1^2\cdot 2^2\dotsm n^2.$$